Weird Memory usage change on pandas dataframe after change dtype
I am collecting large-scale data from the web and storing it in pandas DataFrames. During this process, I've encountered significant memory usage and attempted to perform memory optimization.
The memory optimization was conducted by changing the dtype of each column to match the type of data it holds. For example, rating_*** columns, which consist of integers ranging from 1 to 5, were converted to int8. However, after applying my memory optimization functions to the collected data (I created two types due to some anomalies), the results were unexpected.

The functions are designed not to operate in-place, and I even used copy(deep=True) just in case. Nonetheless, applying the functions to the original DataFrame (df_test) - which do not operate in-place and return a new DataFrame with optimized memory - changes the memory usage of df_test.

To investigate this issue, I created a deep copy (df_backup) of df_test before running the code and repeated the same experiment. This time, the memory usage of df_backup also changed.

Suspecting it might be an issue with the environment in which the code was executed, I tested it in two different environments. The same problem occurs on both Windows 10 & Python 3.11 & pandas 2.1.3, and Linux & Python 3.10 & pandas 1.5.3 (Google Colab).

The same results are observed whether I measure memory usage using df.memory_usage(deep=True) or sys.getsizeof(df).


I have spent 4 hours trying to resolve this issue but to no avail.
What could be the problem?
And why does the memory usage increase after optimization?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# ----- Define memory optimize functions -----


def squeeze_memory(raw_df):
    df = raw_df.copy()
    # Change rating columns to int8
    for col in ['rating_overall', 'rating_promotion_opportunities', 'rating_welfare_and_salary', 'rating_work_life_balance', 'rating_corporate_culture', 'rating_management']:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('int8')
        
    # Convert the 'date_written' to datetime
    df['date_written'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_written'], errors='coerce')
    
    # Convert columns with a small number of unique values to category
    category_cols = ['company_name', 'industry', 'job', 'employment_status', 'location', 'one_year_later', 'recommendation']
    for col in category_cols:
#         print(col, len(df[col].unique()))
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    
    return df



def optimize_memory(df):
    # Internally define the optimal types for columns
    cat_cols = ['company_name', 'industry', 'job', 'employment_status', 'location', 'one_year_later', 'recommendation']
    int_cols = ['rating_overall', 'rating_promotion_opportunities', 'rating_welfare_and_salary', 'rating_work_life_balance', 'rating_corporate_culture', 'rating_management']
    dt_cols = ['date_written']
    
    # Create an empty dataframe
    my_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for col in df.columns:
        # Optimize column types
        if col in cat_cols:
            my_df[col] = df[col].copy().astype('category')
        elif col in int_cols:
            # Rating columns are sufficient with int8
            my_df[col] = df[col].copy().astype('int8')
        elif col in dt_cols:
            # Convert date columns to datetime, specify format
            my_df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col].copy(), format='%Y. %m', errors='coerce')
        else:
            # Check if it's possible to reduce memory usage for the other columns
            if df[col].copy().dtype == 'float64':
                # Change float64 columns to float32
                my_df[col] = df[col].copy().astype('float32')
            elif df[col].copy().dtype == 'object':
                # Optimize object type columns considering the length of strings and the number of unique values
                num_unique_values = df[col].copy().nunique()
                num_total_values = len(df[col].copy())
                if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
                    # If the ratio of unique values to total values is low, convert to category type
                    my_df[col] = df[col].copy().astype('category')
                else:
                    # Otherwise, maintain the existing type
                    my_df[col] = df[col].copy()
            else:
                # In other cases, maintain the existing type
                my_df[col] = df[col].copy()

    return my_df


# ----- Set dataframe for test -----

# Constructing a random df_test DataFrame
np.random.seed(0)
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'company_name': np.random.choice(['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C', 'Company D'], size=2000),
    'industry': np.random.choice(['IT', 'Service', 'Manufacturing', 'Finance'], size=2000),
    'job': np.random.choice(['Development', 'Marketing', 'HR', 'Sales'], size=2000),
    'employment_status': np.random.choice(['Employed', 'Resigned'], size=2000),
    'location': np.random.choice(['Seoul', 'Busan', 'Daegu', 'Gwangju'], size=2000),
    'date_written': np.random.choice(pd.date_range(start='2005-01-01', periods=7000, freq='D').astype(str), size=2000),
    'rating_overall': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    'rating_promotion_opportunities': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    'rating_welfare_and_salary': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    'rating_work_life_balance': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    'rating_corporate_culture': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    'rating_management': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    'title': [f'Title_{i}'*250 for i in range(2000)],
    'pros': [f'Pros_{i}'*250 for i in range(2000)],
    'cons': [f'Cons_{i}'*250 for i in range(2000)],
    'advice_to_management': [f'Advice_{i}'*200 for i in range(2000)],
    'one_year_later': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], size=2000),
    'recommendation': np.random.choice(['Recommend', 'Do Not Recommend'], size=2000)
})



# ----- Run optimization and check memory usages -----

# Code to check memory usage
def memory_usage_of_dataframe(my_df):
    mem_usage = my_df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
#     mem_usage = sys.getsizeof(my_df)
    return mem_usage


df_backup = df_test.copy(deep=True)


print('df_test:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test))
print('df_backup:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_backup))


# Original DataFrame's memory usage
original_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test)

# Applying the optimize_memory function
optimized_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(optimize_memory(df_test))

# Applying the squeeze_memory function
squeezed_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(squeeze_memory(df_test))

print( f"1st measure: {original_memory:,} | {optimized_memory:,} | {squeezed_memory:,}" )




# Original DataFrame's memory usage
original_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test)

# Applying the optimize_memory function
optimized_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(optimize_memory(df_test))

# Applying the squeeze_memory function
squeezed_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(squeeze_memory(df_test))

print( f"2nd measure: {original_memory:,} | {optimized_memory:,} | {squeezed_memory:,}" )


print('df_test:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test))
print('df_backup:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_backup))


# ----- Result -----

df_test: 26576634
df_backup: 26576634
1st measure: 26,576,634 | 45,045,679 | 45,045,679
2nd measure: 46,533,004 | 45,045,679 | 45,045,679
df_test: 46533004
df_backup: 46533004


# ---- UPDATE: English case does not reproduce the memory problem. ----

df_test: 18932963
df_backup: 18932963
1st measure: 18,932,963 | 17,846,054 | 17,846,054
2nd measure: 18,932,963 | 17,846,054 | 17,846,054
df_test: 18932963
df_backup: 18932963


I have tried everything I could
------ Update -----
I discovered this happens when I use Korean instead of English. In my situation, my original data, which I scraped from the web, was in Korean, including the column names. When asking here, I translated the columns and values into English, and after posting my question, I noticed the memory issue didn't arise.
Below is the original code in Korean I used for testing. The memory issue I mentioned persists (it doesn't happen when I switch the column names and values from Korean to English). Nothing has changed except the translation(this is the original code).
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# ----- Define memory optimize functions -----


def squeeze_memory(raw_df):
    df = raw_df.copy(deep=True)
    # 평점 컬럼을 int8으로 변경
    for col in ['평점_전체', '평점_승진 기회 및 가능성', '평점_복지 및 급여', '평점_업무와 삶의 균형', '평점_사내문화', '평점_경영진']:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('int8')

    # 작성일을 datetime으로 변경
    df['작성일'] = pd.to_datetime(df['작성일'], errors='coerce')

    # 적은 수의 유니크 값을 가지는 컬럼을 category로 변경
    category_cols = ['회사명', '업종', '직무', '재직상태', '지역', '1년후', '추천여부']
    for col in category_cols:
#         print(col, len(df[col].unique()))
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')

        
    # for col in ['제목', '장점', '단점', '경영진에게 바라는 점']:
    #     df[col] = df[col].astype('string[pyarrow]')

    return df



def optimize_memory(df):
    # 컬럼별로 최적화할 타입을 내부적으로 정의
    cat_cols = ['회사명', '업종', '직무', '재직상태', '지역', '1년후', '추천여부']
    int_cols = ['평점_전체', '평점_승진 기회 및 가능성', '평점_복지 및 급여', '평점_업무와 삶의 균형', '평점_사내문화', '평점_경영진']
    dt_cols = ['작성일']

    # 빈 데이터프레임 생성
    my_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for col in df.columns:
        # 컬럼 타입 최적화
        if col in cat_cols:
            my_df[col] = df[col].copy(deep=True).astype('category')
        elif col in int_cols:
            # 평점 컬럼은 int8로 충분
            my_df[col] = df[col].copy(deep=True).astype('int8')
        elif col in dt_cols:
            # 날짜 컬럼은 datetime으로 변환, 포맷 지정
            my_df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col].copy(deep=True), format='%Y. %m', errors='coerce')
        else:
            # 나머지 컬럼들에 대해서도 메모리 사용량을 줄일 수 있는지 확인
            if df[col].copy(deep=True).dtype == 'float64':
                # float64 컬럼은 float32로 변경
                my_df[col] = df[col].copy(deep=True).astype('float32')
            elif df[col].copy(deep=True).dtype == 'object':
                # object 타입의 컬럼은 문자열 길이와 고유값의 수를 고려하여 최적화
                num_unique_values = df[col].copy(deep=True).nunique()
                num_total_values = len(df[col].copy(deep=True))
                if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
                    # 고유값의 비율이 전체 값에 비해 낮으면 category 타입으로 변환
                    my_df[col] = df[col].copy(deep=True).astype('category')
                else:
                    # 그렇지 않으면 기존 타입 유지
                    my_df[col] = df[col].copy(deep=True)
            else:
                # 나머지 경우 기존 타입 유지
                my_df[col] = df[col].copy(deep=True)

    return my_df


# ----- Set dataframe for test -----


# 임의의 df_test DataFrame 구성
np.random.seed(0)
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    '회사명': np.random.choice(['회사A', '회사B', '회사C', '회사D'], size=2000),
    '업종': np.random.choice(['IT', '서비스', '제조', '금융'], size=2000),
    '직무': np.random.choice(['개발', '마케팅', '인사', '영업'], size=2000),
    '재직상태': np.random.choice(['재직', '퇴직'], size=2000),
    '지역': np.random.choice(['서울', '부산', '대구', '광주'], size=2000),
    '작성일': np.random.choice(pd.date_range(start='2005-01-01', periods=7000, freq='D').astype(str), size=2000),
    '평점_전체': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    '평점_승진 기회 및 가능성': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    '평점_복지 및 급여': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    '평점_업무와 삶의 균형': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    '평점_사내문화': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    '평점_경영진': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=2000),
    '제목': [f'제목_{i}'*250 for i in range(2000)],
    '장점': [f'장점_{i}'*250 for i in range(2000)],
    '단점': [f'단점_{i}'*250 for i in range(2000)],
    '경영진에게 바라는 점': [f'바람_{i}'*200 for i in range(2000)],
    '1년후': np.random.choice(['예', '아니오'], size=2000),
    '추천여부': np.random.choice(['추천', '비추천'], size=2000)
})




# 메모리 사용량 확인 코드 작성
def memory_usage_of_dataframe(my_df):
    mem_usage = my_df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
#     mem_usage = sys.getsizeof(my_df)
    return mem_usage



# ----- Run optimization and check memory usages -----

df_backup = df_test.copy(deep=True)


print('df_test:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test))
print('df_backup:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_backup))


# 원본 DataFrame의 메모리 사용량
original_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test)

# optimize_memory 함수 적용
optimized_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(optimize_memory(df_test))

# squeeze_memory 함수 적용
squeezed_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(squeeze_memory(df_test))

print( f"1st measure: {original_memory:,} | {optimized_memory:,} | {squeezed_memory:,}" )




# 원본 DataFrame의 메모리 사용량
original_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test)

# optimize_memory 함수 적용
optimized_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(optimize_memory(df_test))

# squeeze_memory 함수 적용
squeezed_memory = memory_usage_of_dataframe(squeeze_memory(df_test))

print( f"2nd measure: {original_memory:,} | {optimized_memory:,} | {squeezed_memory:,}" )


print('df_test:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test))
print('df_backup:', memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_backup))


# ----- Result -----

df_test: 26576634
df_backup: 26576634
1st measure: 26,576,634 | 45,045,679 | 45,045,679
2nd measure: 46,533,004 | 45,045,679 | 45,045,679
df_test: 46533004
df_backup: 46533004


I cannot reproduce this. I get a size of 18,740,967 for the original, which gets reduced to 17,781,882 with both the "optimize" and the "squeeze". this is for pandas version 2.2.0 on MacOS

my suggestion would be to try to narrow this down a bit more. What columns are necessary for you to reproduce this problem? For example, if you remove all the numeric columns, or if you remove all the object columns... try to wittle down the problem a bit. that is how I would start (in other words, create a [mcve])

Actually, my problem was originally written in Korean. I had data and column names in Korean, but I translated everything into English to ask a question on Stack Overflow. I thought the issue wasn't language-dependent, so I simply posted my question. However, after running the code in English again, the problem disappeared. But with the code in Korean, the issue still occurs. I've updated the original Korean code in the main text that's causing the problem.

Your code already reduces memory use. There is still a bit of margin for improvement by casting to the string[pyarrow] type your string columns. In here I add the improvement:
def squeeze_memory(raw_df):
    df = raw_df.copy()
    # Change rating columns to int8
    for col in ['rating_overall', 'rating_promotion_opportunities', 'rating_welfare_and_salary', 'rating_work_life_balance', 'rating_corporate_culture', 'rating_management']:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('int8')
        
    # Convert the 'date_written' to datetime
    df['date_written'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_written'], errors='coerce')
    
    # Convert columns with a small number of unique values to category
    category_cols = ['company_name', 'industry', 'job', 'employment_status', 'location', 'one_year_later', 'recommendation']
    for col in category_cols:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')

    for col in ['title', 'pros', 'cons', 'advice_to_management']:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('string[pyarrow]')
    
    return df

You can benchmark the reduction column by column with a single loop:
sm_df = squeeze_memory(df_test)

benchmark = []
for col in sm_df.columns:
    col_mem = memory_usage_of_dataframe(sm_df.loc[:,[col]])
    orig_mem = memory_usage_of_dataframe(df_test.loc[:,[col]])
    benchmark.append([col, sm_df[col].dtype, col_mem,df_test[col].dtype, orig_mem, orig_mem-col_mem])

pd.DataFrame(benchmark, columns=["column name", "new type", "new mem size", "old type", "old mem size", "mem improvement"])


There is definately a reduction in all columns. Although it cannot make miracles since you are storing really long strings which is taking a noticeble amount of space. If this is not enough I would suggest to try out something like polars to test if can improve towards your desired performance.

This doesn't really answer the question

Thank you for your answer; it has reduced memory usage. I believe the reason the compressed dataframe uses more memory than before is due to this issue. However, this is somewhat separate from the main problem.

Apologies, I was missing crucial information. I will keep the answer in case it helps anyone else feel free to ignore it.
